# Which part of leg should be used in Muay Thai Round Head kicks?

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, kicking, muay-thai

Which part of leg should be used in Muay Thai Round Head kicks? The Foot, top of Ankle, or Shin? My coach always taught on top of Ankle with it flexed, "bridge between Shin and Foot". However most online people will say Shin.

However, I saw a video of headkicks, and almost majority of them are using some part of the ankle or foot, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qaww12nR7MI

[image]

top of ankle flexed, so feet, is not in the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend partly upon how close you are to your opponent.

The foot has a greater potential velocity due to the greater arc it traverses en route to the opponent.

The shin has a lesser potential velocity, but is far more rigid than the foot, and perhaps less prone to damage than the top of the foot when making contact with a head.

The top of the ankle is reasonably robust in the context of head kicks, and provides a good 'middle ground', allowing for a margin of error both up and down the limb when gauging the range of your attack.

Successful execution of a roundhouse head kick will likely reap dividends regardless of whether contact is achieved via the foot, the top of ankle or the shin, and it is definitely worth incorporating each into your training regimen.

When kicking opponent's body or lower leg, the shin will often be more appropriate, depending upon the striker's skill level, conditioning, and the purpose of the kick.

This brief [Fight Tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZnJUDQGSpE) video provides supporting info and demonstration.

Comment: @mattsmith5. I'm not a Muay Thai expert. I have dabbled. My background is  Kyokushin Karate and boxing, and a graduate diploma in education. I have a solid understanding of teaching, biomechanics, strategy and technique, particularly related to martial arts striking, which enables me to confidently answer many cross disciplinary questions, such as your questions about bouncing, parrying and kicking. Be skeptical of all advice. Test it. Research widely. Any unsound advice I offer will be quickly identified and downvoted by the SE elders. It's not error-proof, but it's a fairly reliable system.